# Update current value on mousemove for all lines in stock highcharts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts, stock-highcharts

When mouse is moved, I want to update the `current value` field of **datagrid** for both the lines. Unfortunately, it is updating for signal line when mouse is hovered over a particular line as you can see here:

**DEMO** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-7d79lt?file=stockchart%2Fstockchart.js

I kind of know it is because I'm attaching **mouseOver** callback to `point` property of `plotOptions`

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
          // compare: 'percent',
          showInNavigator: true,
          dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          point: {
            events: {
              mouseOver: (e) => {
                const temp = [...stockGrid];
                const stock = temp.find((x) => x.name === e.target.series.name);
                if (stock) {
                  stock.currentValue = e.target.options.y;
                  setStockGrid(temp);
                }
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
```

I tried attaching **mouseOver** to `series` also but I don't know how to extract right value with it.

I want to update both lines' current value **simultaneously** when mouse is moving anywhere in the chart.

---

**2)** If you look at the tooltip, I want to get rid of the outer rectangle from all tooltips. I tried setting `tooltip.borderWidth` to 0   , This removes the outer rectangle but it also removes tooltip connection line to vertical line. I need a line between vertical line (from line point to tooltip) and tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can iterate through all chart series and check if any of points has the same x value as hovered one.

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            let hoveredPoint = this,
              text = '';

            hoveredPoint.series.chart.series.forEach(series => {
              if (hoveredPoint.series.name != series.name) {
                series.points.forEach(point => {
                  if (hoveredPoint.x === point.x) {
                    text += point.series.name + ': ' + point.y + ', ' + hoveredPoint.series.name + ': ' + hoveredPoint.y;

                    console.log(text)
                  }
                })
              }
            })
          },
        }
      }
    },
  },
```

**Simplified demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/75Lkw4qj/

**2)**  Have you considered removing the inner border instead?

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-6asjx2?file=stockchart%2Fstockchart.js